# Raspberry Pi Print Server with CUPS printer detected but not printing

Tags: printing, raspberrypi, cups-lpd

So I set up my Brother DCP-J125 on my Pi, had to install external drivers (which work on my notebook) installes and configured cups. enabled network sharing choose the driver. I even found the printer imidietly over the network from my windows and Ubuntu machines and sent print requests but nothing happens. lpstat says the the printer is waiting for requests in idle but nothing gets fulfillid. Like I said I got the same printer working on my ubuntu machine directly via usb and cups but not over the pi.

my only idea is that I have to install one more additional little thin on the pi which I installed on my notebook already while trubelshooting or ubuntu has built in instead of rasbian.

I run rasbian lite so threre is really not much there. any ideas?

Comment: On the Pi, at `http://localhost:631/admin` did you set "Share ..."?

Comment: @waltinator yeah as I said it is even visible in the network